# Terraform Conditionals in AWS Module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

Earlier today I was looking at https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/v2.77.0/main.tf to look deeper into how the VPC module for AWS works behind the scenes.

One thing that I am struggling with is the count conditional such as the one in the aws_internet_gateway resource.

Can someone explain and translate what the count defined in this resource is actually doing? It's very confusing to me at the moment.

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "this" {
  count = var.create_vpc && var.create_igw && length(var.public_subnets) > 0 ? 1 : 0

  vpc_id = local.vpc_id

  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = format("%s", var.name)
    },
    var.tags,
    var.igw_tags,
  )
}
```

Comment: How did it go with the conditions? Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses [ternary operation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#conditionals) in the general form of:

```
CONDITION ? TRUEVAL : FALSEVAL
```

In the module, the

```
CONDITION is var.create_vpc && var.create_igw && length(var.public_subnets) > 0

TRUEVAL is 1

FALSEVAL is 0
```

This **translates** to the following: If both `create_vpc` and `create_igw` are `true` as well as  `public_subnets` has been defined, then `count` will be `1` (`TRUEVAL`) and  exactly one `aws_internet_gateway.this` will be created.

In contrast if the `CONDITION` is not satisfied, `count` will be `0` (`FALSEVAL`) and no `aws_internet_gateway.this` will be created.

In general, it is a **common pattern** to [conditionally create](https://dev.to/tbetous/how-to-make-conditionnal-resources-in-terraform-440n) resources in terraform:

```
resource "type" "name" {

  count = CONDITION : 1 ? 0

}
```